# Bind click handler with variables in scope when created?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a list of items dynamically in jQuery, and dynamically bind a click handler to each one, with the variables in scope at the moment the click handler is created.

The code below creates a list of items from 1-6, but the click handler only seems to bind with the value of the final item - the alert always shows 6.

Is this a JavaScript scope problem? How can I bind the alerts with variables from 1-6?

HTML:

```
<ul id="saved-list">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var all_cookies = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
for (var i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
    var route_num = all_cookies[i]; 
    var list_item = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>";
    list_item += "<p>" + route_num + "</p></a></li>";
    var newLi = $(list_item);
    newLi.bind('click', function(){
        alert(route_num);
    });
    $('#saved-list').append(newLi);      
}
```

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n6FU5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic JavaScript confusion between "scope" and "curly braces". It turns out that curly braces have little to do with scope in JavaScript. Scope only arises from *functions*.

One consequence of this is that variables are always hoisted to the top of the scope, i.e. the nearest function. So your code is exactly equivalent to:

```
var all_cookies = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var i;
var route_num;
var list_item;
var newLi;

for (i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
    route_num = all_cookies[i]; 
    list_item = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>";
    list_item += "<p>" + route_num + "</p></a></li>";
    newLi = $(list_item);
    newLi.bind('click', function(){
        alert(route_num);
    });
    $('#saved-list').append(newLi);      
}
```

With this in mind, you can see how, since `route_num` is the same variable every time through the loop, after the loop is over its value is set to `6`, and in the future whenever the click handler is called, the `6` is what you see.

One way to fix this is to wrap the contents of your loop in a self-executing anonymous function:

```
var all_cookies = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
for (var i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
    (function () { 
        var route_num = all_cookies[i]; 
        var list_item = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>";
        list_item += "<p>" + route_num + "</p></a></li>";
        var newLi = $(list_item);
        newLi.bind('click', function(){
            alert(route_num);
        });
        $('#saved-list').append(newLi);      
    }());
}
```

That way, when the variables get hoisted, they will just get hoisted to the top of that inner self-executing function, and so there will be different instances of them for each run through the loop.

Comment: Ooooo. Likes :). I came up with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/n6FU5/2/, though not as pretty, it has a funny function inside xD

Comment: +1, nice solution, although I wouldn't be too happy if I'd have to debug someone's code filled with fiddles like this. Nest a few of these, and it's an effective way to obfuscate your code to give your co-developers some nightmares. :)

Comment: @DarthJDG: since this is actually a pretty common technique in JavaScript, it's not too surprising to anyone familiar with the language.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that your onclick function is returning the value of the variable route_num at the time the link is clicked.  route_num is a global variable and the value is left set to 6 when the loop finishes running.  So what you need to do is set the function to alert the value of route_num at the time the for loop is running.

The way to do this is to construct the function as a string so that you can append the value of the string to function definition.  Here is an example of what I *think* you were trying to accomplish.

```
var all_cookies = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
for (var i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) { 
    var route_num = all_cookies[i];  

    var list_item = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>"; 
    list_item += "<p>" + route_num + "</p></a></li>"; 
    var newLi = $(list_item);

    var fn = new Function("alert('" + route_num + "');");
    newLi.bind('click', fn); 

    $('#saved-list').append(newLi);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the way javascript works. The variables in scope ARE accessible as you found out, but they are not separate instances for each sub-scope. Therefore your variable's value IS 6 at the time the handler function is called.

The solution is to save `route_num` in a data attribute and retrieve it inside your click handler.

```
var all_cookies = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
    var route_num = all_cookies[i];
    var list_item = "<li><a href='#saved-route'>";
    list_item += "<p>" + route_num + "</p></a></li>";

    var newLi = $(list_item);
    newLi.data('routenum', route_num);
    newLi.bind('click', function() {
        alert($(this).data('routenum'));
    });

    $('#saved-list').append(newLi);
}
```

Here's your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6FU5/1/

Comment: Can't you do something magically to trick the scope? Using data is such an boring solution, there needs to be a pure-js way around this, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a very heavy-handed way of solving the problem, involving as it does manipulating DOM elements and the like.

Comment: Like it or not, I still think this solution is easier to understand and debug than creating embedded anonymous functions to force scope.