# KineticJS array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, canvas, kineticjs

I have a problem with kinetics object:

I have some kinetics objects...

```
var trianguloG1 = new Kinetic.Polygon({ 
points: [x, y, catetosTiangulosGrandes+x, y, x, catetosTiangulosGrandes+y, x, y],
fill: '#7e4f00',
draggable: true
});
layer.add(trianguloG1);
```

Next objects are similar...

Now, I want apply shadow effects in objects (using an array) on click event, but I have an error

```
var figuras = [ "trianguloG1",
                 "trianguloMediano",
                 "cuadrado",
                 "trianguloPeque1",
                 "trianguloG2",
                 "trianguloPeque2",
                 "paralelogramo1",
                 "paralelogramoEspejo" ];
for(i=0; i<figuras.length; i++) {
    var figurita=figuras[i];
console.log(figurita);
figurita.on('click', function() { //TypeError: figurita.on is not a function
    figurita.setShadowBlur(8);

            //....... more code
```

Is possible to do this using an array? What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Get rid of the quotes, e.g. figuras=[trianguloG1, ...

Comment: Ok. Now it's ok but don't work: `var figuras=[trianguloG1,trianguloMediano,cuadrado,trianguloPeque1,trianguloG2,trianguloPeque2,paralelogramo1,paralelogramoEspejo];
for(i=0;i<figuras.length;i++) {
 var figurita=figuras[i];
 console.log(figurita);
 figurita.on('click', function() {
 figurita.setShadowBlur(8);
 figurita.setShadowColor("black");
 figurita.setShadowOffset(3);
 figurita.setShadowOpacity(0.7);
 stage.add(layer); 
 });`   but this works perfectly: `trianguloG1.on('click', function() {
 trianguloG1.setShadowBlur(8);
 ....`

Comment: @Gozacid: I think you need to redraw the layer or something along those lines...

Comment: layer.draw() I think... The layer is already in your stage right?

Comment: yes: `stage.add(layer); ` is included in click event. The problem is only using the array. if I use objects one to one works ok

Comment: OK.  I see what you're saying.  I think it has to do with the lambda not being able to see figurita.  I'm not really a JS guy was just browsing idly but I think I've seen this.

Comment: I think you need to do this extra scope thing along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828718/javascript-scope-problem-when-lambda-function-refers-to-a-variable-in-enclosing

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169313/bind-click-handler-with-variables-in-scope-when-created

Comment: Did that make sense?  Basically it's about what figurita inside your click function refers to.  If the links don't make sense I can try correcting your code...

Comment: I can not make it work...

Comment: solved using this! `for(i=0;i<figuras.length;i++) {
 figuras[i].on('click', function() {
 this.setShadowColor("black");
 this.setShadowBlur(8);
 this.setShadowOffset(3);
 this.setShadowOpacity(0.7);
 stage.add(layer); 
 });
}`

Comment: Cool.. Yes, that'll work too.  If I were you I'd spend a little time trying to get it work the other way just to get a better understanding of what's going on...